# Can't get meta values to save

Tags: metabox, meta-value

I'm trying to write a class to make meta boxes. The boxes display fine, but I can't seem to get the values to save. It seems like the Save function isn't being called at all.

As a further experiment, I added a meta value to the database manually, and it displayed just fine in the editor, but when I clicked "Update", the entry was deleted.

Any advice would be appreciated. Here's my code.

```
    /**
 * Reusable custom meta boxes class
 *
 * Reusable custom meta boxes
 * Part of Cloudsmith WP-Framework used to help create custom post types for Wordpress.
 *
 * @author  Cloudsmith Studio
 * @link    https://cloudsmith.ca
 * @version 1.0
 * @license 
 */

class Cloudsmith_Meta_Box {

    /**
     * Meta Box ID
     *
     * @var string $box_id Holds id of the custom meta box to be created.
     */
    public $box_id;

    /**
     * Meta Box Title
     *
     * @var string $box_title Holds the title of the meta box
     */
    public $box_title;

    /**
     * Meta Box Content
     *
     * @var string $box_context Holds the context parameter for the meta box
     */
    public $box_context;

    public $box_priority;

    public $box_post_type;

    /**
     * Meta Box Content
     *
     * @var array $box_meat_fields Holds an array of arrays for the fileds to be displayed in a meta box
     */
    public $box_meta_fields;


    public static function create( $title, $fields = array(), $post_type, $context = 'normal', $priority = 'high' ){

        // If the Parameters are Empty, Do nothing
        if( ! empty ( $title ) ){

            // Instanitate a new object for the meta box
            ${$title . '_meta_box'} = new Cloudsmith_Meta_Box;


            // Assign the properties
            ${$title . '_meta_box'}->box_id          = Cloudsmith_Utility::uglify( $title ) . '_meta_box';
            ${$title . '_meta_box'}->box_title       = Cloudsmith_Utility::prettify( $title );
            ${$title . '_meta_box'}->box_context     = $context;
            ${$title . '_meta_box'}->box_priority    = $priority;
            ${$title . '_meta_box'}->box_post_type   = $post_type;
            ${$title . '_meta_box'}->box_meta_fields = $fields;

            $meta_box = ${$title . '_meta_box'};
            add_action( 'admin_init', 
                function() use( $meta_box ) {

                    add_meta_box(
                        $meta_box->box_id ,
                        $meta_box->box_title,
                        [ $meta_box, 'display_meta_box' ],
                        $meta_box->box_post_type,
                        $meta_box->box_context,
                        $meta_box->box_priority,
                        $meta_box->box_meta_fields
                    );
                    add_action('save_post', [ $meta_box, 'save_meta_value' ] );
                }
            );

        }
     } // End of Create Method

     public function display_meta_box(){


        global $post;

        // use nonce for input verification
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->box_id . '_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce( basename( __FILE__ ) ).'" />';

        // loop through $fields array to create form inputs.
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ( $this->box_meta_fields as $field ){

            // Get value for this field if it exists
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field['id'], true );

            // Begin table row
            echo
                '<tr>
                    <th><label for="' . $field['id'] . '">' . $field['label'] . '</label></th>
                    <td>';

                        // display HTML based on the type of input
                        switch( $field['type'] ){

                            // Text input
                            case 'text':
                                echo '<input type="text" name="' . $field['id'] . '" id="' . $field['id'] . '" value="'. $meta_value . '" size="30" />';
                                echo '</br><span class="description">' . $field['desc'] . '</span>';
                            break;

                            // Text Area Input
                            case 'textarea':
                                echo '<textarea name="' . $field['id'] . '" id="' . $field['id'] . '" cols="60" rows="4">'. $meta_value . '</textarea>';
                                echo '</br><span class="description">' . $field['desc'] . '</span>';
                            break;

                            // Select Box input
                            case 'select':
                                echo '<select>';
                                while ( list( $key, $value ) = each( $field['options'] ) ){
                                    echo '<option ', $meta_value == $value ? 'selected="selected"' : '', 'value="' . $value .'">' . $key . '</option>';
                                }
                                echo '</select><br>';
                                echo '<span class ="description">' . $field['desc'] . '</span>';
                            break;

                            // Checkbox input

                            case 'checkbox':
                                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'. $field['id'] .'" id="' . $field['id'] .'"', $meta_value ? 'checked="checked"' : '','/>';
                                echo '<label for"' . $field['id'] . '">' . $field['desc'] . '</label>';
                            break;

                            // Single Select Radio Box input
                            case 'radio':

                            break;

                        } // End of switch
                    echo 
                    '</td>
                </tr>';
        } // End foreach

        echo '</table>'; // end of input table
     }

     public function save_meta_value( $post_id ) {

        global $post;

        echo '<div class="notice updated"><p>Saved!!!??</p></div>';
        //var_dump($this->box_meta_fields);

        // verify nonce
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST[$this->box_id . '_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) 
            return $post_id;
        // check autosave
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return $post_id;
        // check permissions
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
                return $post_id;
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
                return $post_id;
        }

        // loop through fields and save the data
        foreach ($this->box_meta_fields as $field) {
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
            if ($new && $new != $old) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
            }
        } // end foreach
    }
} // End of Meta Box Class
```

And then I call my methods here:

```
    // Create a new custome post type for quizzes.
$quizzes = new Cloudsmith_Custom_Post_Type( 'Quiz', 'Quizzes', $args );

// Add taxonomies to the quiz post type
Cloudsmith_Taxonomy::create( 'quiz_category', 'quiz', 'Category', 'Categories', ['hierarchical' => true] );
Cloudsmith_Taxonomy::create( 'quiz_tags', 'quiz', 'Tag', 'Tags' );
Cloudsmith_Taxonomy::create( 'quiz_difficulty', 'quiz', 'Difficulty Level', 'Difficulty Levels', 
    // custom taxonomy settings
    [
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => false
    ] 
);

Cloudsmith_Meta_Box::create( 'Questions',
    [
        [
            'label' => 'First Question',
            'desc'  => 'What is the question you want to ask?',
            'id'    => "Question One",
            'type'  => 'text'
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Second Question',
            'desc'  => 'Do you have another question?',
            'id'    => 'Question Two',
            'type'  => 'checkbox'
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Third Question',
            'desc'  => 'How many more?',
            'id'    => 'Question Three',
            'type'  => 'textarea'
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Fourth Question',
            'desc'  => 'At least 2',
            'id'    => 'Question 4',
            'type'  => 'select',
            'options' => 
                [
                    'option 1' => 'one',
                    'option 2' => 'two',
                    'option 3' => 'three'
                ]
        ]
    ],
    'quiz'
);

Cloudsmith_Meta_Box::create( 'Answers',
    [
        [
            'label' => 'First Answer',
            'desc'  => 'Do Two boxes work?',
            'id'    => "Answer One",
            'type'  => 'text'
        ]
    ],
    'quiz'
);
```

Comment: Isn't it a nonce value issue, look the source code to see the generated value, I think you'll never get the generated value with wp_create_nonce.

Comment: I've tried running the code with all the security checks deleted, and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

There was a space in the field ID, and the $_POST key would collapse it. So the ID's weren't matching up in the foreach loop in my save function.

I solved this with a sanitizing function on the IDs for my meta fields.

I was further confused because my admin notices that I inserted to help me debug weren't showing. I didn't know that after saving the post, the page redirects, and the admin notices aren't seen by the user. Therefore, I thought the save_post action wasn't firing at all, when in fact it was.